# Capistrano testing for release directory and failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano3

We upgraded from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.2 and Capistrano from 3.2.1 to 3.4.

Now it seems *capistrano* does not create the release-directory before it tests for it. Which results in an error:

```
** Invoke test (first_time)
** Execute test
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke bundler:map_bins (first_time)
** Execute bundler:map_bins
** Invoke rvm:hook (first_time)
** Execute rvm:hook
** Invoke rvm:check (first_time)
** Execute rvm:check
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_rails_env
** Invoke deploy:set_linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_linked_dirs
** Invoke deploy (first_time)
** Execute deploy
** Invoke deploy:starting (first_time)
** Execute deploy:starting
** Invoke deploy:check (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check
** Invoke copy:check (first_time)
** Execute copy:check
** Invoke deploy:check:directories (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:directories
** Invoke deploy:check:linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:linked_dirs
** Invoke deploy:check:make_linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:make_linked_dirs
** Invoke dcportal:db:create_config (first_time)
** Execute dcportal:db:create_config
** Invoke deploy:check:linked_files (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:linked_files
** Invoke deploy:set_previous_revision (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_previous_revision
** Invoke deploy:started (first_time)
** Execute deploy:started
** Invoke deploy:updating (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:new_release_path (first_time)
** Execute deploy:new_release_path
** Execute deploy:updating
 DEBUG [84703c58] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rvm ] as cap@softwaredev-it2
** Invoke copy:create_release (first_time)
 DEBUG [84703c58] Command: [ -d ~/.rvm ]
** Invoke copy:deploy (first_time)

[...]

DEBUG [5c4fa563] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/www/rails/dc/releases/20160217135156; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/rails/dc/releases/20160217135156'" 1>&2; false; fi as cap@softwaredev-it2
DEBUG [5c4fa563] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/rails/dc/releases/20160217135156; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/rails/dc/releases/20160217135156'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [5c4fa563]    Directory does not exist '/var/www/rails/dc/releases/20160217135156'
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if I could make an observation: you seem to be using some sort of "copy" scm plugin instead of the standard hg/git/svn. The scm code is what is responsible for creating the release directory; not capistrano itself (at least, this is true as of 3.4). I suggest looking into the scm plugin to see if maybe it needs to be upgraded.

Comment: Thank you. This actually might help. I will post, if it yields something.

Comment: It helped. We've upgraded scm-plugin and now it works.